# How can I create a heightmap for ocean surface simulation?

Tags: c++, simulations, heightmap

I am working on a game that is based on boats fighiting each other. The game is finished but due to some license incopatibilities, I have to change how I simulate the surface of the sea.

What I used until now was a mesh with all the vertices of the sea, and I was setting each vertex's height using FFT (with a library that is the one I can't use). Now I don't have time to port it to another FFT library, so do you know any sine / cosine based formula or any other "easy" method that I can use to compute the height of each vertex which also keeps consistency between frames?

Having the game finished I need to keep some features of the previous implementation like it has to be CPU computed because the sea surface is affecting the boat's rotation.

Comment: [Have you looked into Gerstner waves](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gerstner+wave&ia=web)?

Comment: @DMGregory no, I have not. I will have a look at it. Thanks!